# Using newtype with Beam

Tags: haskell, haskell-beam

I used to have `Email` as `type Email = T.Text`.

I changed it to:

```
newtype Email = Email { unEmail :: T.Text }
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

This change created an error in:

```
instance Table UserT where
   data PrimaryKey UserT f = UserId (Columnar f T.Text) deriving (Generic, Beamable)
   primaryKey = UserId . _userAddressEmail
```

The error:

```
backend/src/Backend.hs:145:17-22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Columnar column T.Text’
                     with ‘Columnar column Email’
      Expected type: Columnar column Email -> PrimaryKey UserT column
        Actual type: Columnar column T.Text -> PrimaryKey UserT column
      NB: ‘Columnar’ is a non-injective type family
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘UserId’
      In the expression: UserId . _userAddressEmail
      In an equation for ‘primaryKey’:
          primaryKey = UserId . _userAddressEmail
    • Relevant bindings include
        primaryKey :: UserT column -> PrimaryKey UserT column
          (bound at backend/src/Backend.hs:145:4)
    |
145 |    primaryKey = UserId . _userAddressEmail
    |                 ^^^^^^
```

I tried:

```
instance Table UserT where
   data PrimaryKey UserT f = UserId (Columnar f T.Text) deriving (Generic, Beamable)
   primaryKey = UserId . (unEmail _userAddressEmail)
```

But I get this error:

```
backend/src/Backend.hs:145:27-51: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘UserT column
                                    -> Columnar column T.Text’
                  with actual type ‘T.Text’
    • Possible cause: ‘unEmail’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
        ‘(unEmail _userAddressEmail)’
      In the expression: UserId . (unEmail _userAddressEmail)
      In an equation for ‘primaryKey’:
          primaryKey = UserId . (unEmail _userAddressEmail)
    • Relevant bindings include
        primaryKey :: UserT column -> PrimaryKey UserT column
          (bound at backend/src/Backend.hs:145:4)
    |
145 |    primaryKey = UserId . (unEmail _userAddressEmail)
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
backend/src/Backend.hs:145:35-51: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Email’
                  with actual type ‘UserT f0 -> Columnar f0 Email’
    • Probable cause: ‘_userAddressEmail’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of ‘unEmail’, namely ‘_userAddressEmail’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
        ‘(unEmail _userAddressEmail)’
      In the expression: UserId . (unEmail _userAddressEmail)
    |
145 |    primaryKey = UserId . (unEmail _userAddressEmail)
    |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I thought `unEmail` would unwrap the type?

This is the entry:

```
data UserT f
    = User
    { _userAddressEmail                 :: Columnar f Email
...
```

Comment: You probably meant to compose `unEmail` rather than apply it to `_userAddressEmail` -- that is, `UserId . unEmail . _userAddressEmail` instead of `UserId . (unEmail _userAddressEmail)`.

Comment: @duplode - I tried that also. It results in: 
``` 
• Couldn't match type ‘Columnar column Email’ with ‘Email’
      Expected type: UserT column -> Email
        Actual type: UserT column -> Columnar column Email
```

Comment: and ```Couldn't match type ‘Columnar column T.Text’ with ‘T.Text’
      Expected type: T.Text -> PrimaryKey UserT column
        Actual type: Columnar column T.Text -> PrimaryKey UserT column```

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I suspect what you intend isn't possible to achieve in this way. Mapping the unwrapper through [`Columnar f`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/beam-core-0.8.0.0/docs/Database-Beam-Schema-Tables.html#t:Columnar) would require, at a minimum, working with a specific `f`, which doesn't seem to make sense in this context. The Beam user guide briefly mentions [domain types](https://tathougies.github.io/beam/user-guide/databases/#domain-types), which sound somewhat relevant; unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Beam to actually help with that right now.